# Tailwind classes that use helper methods stop working after restarting Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, ruby-on-rails-7

I have a Rails 7  app that uses Tailwind CSS. I have flash messages that use a helper method to set the background color of the flash message in the view.

When I restart the server with `./bin/dev` the background colors that use the helper methods (see below the method is `notic_color(key)`) do not affect the background color. In the browser the background color is not being applied. BUT in the browser debugger  the html has the bg-yellow-100 classes in the html.

If I hard code the class names, the background colors work. And then they do take the helper methods into account  after replacing `yellow` with `notic_color(key)`.  BUT after restarting the server the background colors aren't working with the helper methods again.

How  can I make the background colors work correctly after restarting the server?

My code is like this:

helpers/flash_helper.rb

```
module FlashHelper
  GREEN_FLASH_KEYS = %w[notice success].freeze

  def green?(flash_key)
    flash_key.in?(GREEN_FLASH_KEYS)
  end

  def notice_color(flash_key)
    green?(flash_key) ? 'green' : 'yellow'
  end
end
```

layouts/_alert_messages.html.erb - NOTICE THIS `<%= notice_color(key) %>` below in the classes. This is what does not work after re-starting the Rails server:

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div data-controller="toggle"
      data-toggle-classes="hidden"
      data-toggle-target="content"
      id="alert-message"
      class="fixed top-5 left-0 w-full flex items-center justify-center z-50">
    <div class="rounded-md bg-<%= notice_color(key) %>-100 p-4 w-full md:w-3/5">
      <div class="flex">
        <div class="flex-shrink-0">
          <% if green?(key) %>
            <svg class="h-5 w-5 text-<%= notice_color(key) %>-400" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M10 18a8 8 0 100-16 8 8 0 000 16zm3.857-9.809a.75.75 0 00-1.214-.882l-3.483 4.79-1.88-1.88a.75.75 0 10-1.06 1.061l2.5 2.5a.75.75 0 001.137-.089l4-5.5z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
            </svg>
          <% else %>  
            <svg class="h-5 w-5 text-yellow-400" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
              <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M8.485 2.495c.673-1.167 2.357-1.167 3.03 0l6.28 10.875c.673 1.167-.17 2.625-1.516 2.625H3.72c-1.347 0-2.189-1.458-1.515-2.625L8.485 2.495zM10 5a.75.75 0 01.75.75v3.5a.75.75 0 01-1.5 0v-3.5A.75.75 0 0110 5zm0 9a1 1 0 100-2 1 1 0 000 2z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
            </svg>
          <% end %>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-3">
          <p class="text-sm font-medium text-<%= notice_color(key) %>-800">
            <%= value %>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="ml-auto pl-3">
          <div class="-mx-1.5 -my-1.5">
            <button type="button" 
                    data-action="click->toggle#toggle"
                    data-toggle-id-param="alert-message"
                    class="inline-flex rounded-md bg-<%= notice_color(key) %><%= notice_color(key) %>-50 p-1.5 text-<%= notice_color(key) %>-500 hover:bg-<%= notice_color(key) %>-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-<%= notice_color(key) %>-600 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-offset-<%= notice_color(key) %>-50">
              <span class="sr-only">Dismiss</span>
              <svg class="h-5 w-5" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                <path d="M6.28 5.22a.75.75 0 00-1.06 1.06L8.94 10l-3.72 3.72a.75.75 0 101.06 1.06L10 11.06l3.72 3.72a.75.75 0 101.06-1.06L11.06 10l3.72-3.72a.75.75 0 00-1.06-1.06L10 8.94 6.28 5.22z" />
              </svg>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my tailwind.config.js

```
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme')

module.exports = {
  content: [
    './public/*.html',
    './app/helpers/**/*.rb',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js',
    './app/views/**/*.{erb,haml,html,slim}'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Inter var', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
    require('@tailwindcss/line-clamp'),
    require('@tailwindcss/container-queries'),
  ]
}
```

Here is a screenshot that shows the browser and debugger

[image]

If I change this line

```
<div class="rounded-md bg-<%= notice_color(key) %>-100 p-4 w-full md:w-3/5">
```

To this

```
<div class="rounded-md bg-yellow-100 p-4 w-full md:w-3/5">
```

Then I get this

[image]

Comment: The issue is that tailwind will not run ruby code to interpolate which classes to keep. Looking at your helper module, tailwind will just assume that you want the `green` and `yellow` classes, but won't actually know that these strings are only a substring of a class. You have to be more declarative

Comment: I have another form that adds classes like this  <%= f.email_field :email,
                              class: "block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6
                              #{error_class(:email, resource.errors.attribute_names)}" %> and that is from a helper like this def error_class(field, error_attribute_names)
    error?(field, error_attribute_names) ? FORM_FIELD_ERROR_CLASSES : ''
  end and this works

Comment: Why does it work until I restart the server?

Comment: That's probably because your `FORM_FIELD_ERROR_CLASSES` declares the classes in full, not just a substring of them.

Comment: I agree. Thanks for pointing this out. I think a better approach would be to just have a separate partial for each type of flash message. And just stop trying to set the colors.